# Tiles being drawn in the wrong location

Tags: c++, drawing, sfml

I've finally managed to get my tiles drawn on the screen somewhat in a correct way. Although the location is a bit off and I can't seem to figure out why...

I'm using SFML for drawing.

Tile.hpp:

```
#ifndef TILE_HPP
#define TILE_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

#include "textureManager.hpp"

class Tile {
public:
    Tile();
    Tile(sf::Vector2i coord, int biome);
    ~Tile();

    sf::Vector2i getCoord() const { return coord; };
    int getBiome() const { return biome; };

    void setCoord(sf::Vector2i coord) { this->coord = coord; };
    void setBiome(int biome) { this->biome = biome; };

    void draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow* rw);
    void update(sf::Texture& texture);

private:
    sf::Vector2i coord;
    int biome;

    sf::Sprite sprite;
};

#endif
```

Tile.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

#include "textureManager.hpp"
#include "tile.hpp"

Tile::Tile()
{}

Tile::Tile(sf::Vector2i coord, int biome) {
    this->biome = biome;
    this->coord = coord;
}

Tile::~Tile(){}

void Tile::draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow* rw)
{
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    rw->draw(sprite);
}

void Tile::update(sf::Texture& texture)
{
    switch (biome)
    {
        // Not important here
    }
}
```

Now the more relevant part: the drawing

```
void StatePlay::draw(const float dt)
{
    game->window.setView(view);
    game->window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    sf::Vector2f offset = camera.getLocation();
    int newX = (offset.x / map.getTileSize()) - (map.chunkSize / 2);
    int newY = (offset.y / map.getTileSize()) - (map.chunkSize / 2);

    for (int x = 0; x < map.chunkSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.chunkSize; y++)
            {
                Tile tile = map.getTile(newX + x, newY + y);
                tile.draw((newX + x) * map.getTileSize(), (newY + y) * map.getTileSize(), &game->window);
            }
        }

    return;
}

StatePlay::StatePlay(Game* game)
{
    this->game = game;
    sf::Vector2f pos = sf::Vector2f(game->window.getSize()); // 1366x768
    view.setSize(pos);
    pos *= 0.5f; // 688x384
    view.setCenter(pos);

    // Initialize map
    map.init(game->gameTime, game->textureManager.getImage("tileset.png"));

    float w     = (float) map.getWidth(); // 500
    float h     = (float) map.getHeight(); // 500
    w           *= 0.5f; // 250
    h           *= 0.5f; // 250
    w           *= map.getTileSize(); // 250 * 32 = 8000
    h           *= map.getTileSize(); // 250 * 32 = 8000
    // Move camera
    // Uses view::move from sfml to move the view with w and h
    // Also sets camera private to w and h values, return with camera::getLocation()
    camera.setLocation(&view, sf::Vector2f(w, h));
}
```

The result is that I only see the ~10 tiles squared, in the bottom left corner of my screen, covering about 3/4.

[image: Example]

The correct tiles are chosen, but the draw location is wrong... It should draw the center of 64x64 (x 32px each) tiles, as much as fit on the screen.

Comment: What is newX and newY ?
What are you trying to draw with your sprite, you just asign positions... There's no texture nor color. And could you write down just what is going wrong please ?

Comment: I left it out because it was so much code already. The step by step process: `map` is initialized in the `StatePlay` constructor, it generates a default 500x500 tiles map. Then the camera is set to the center of this. (250 x tilesize). This uses `sf::View::move` and updates the location private in the camera class. In the `StatePlay::draw` it loops x and y till < 64, which is the `chunkSize`. So this should draw tiles 218 till 282, on both x and y. The `newX` and `newY` are merely getting the location of the camera and making sure the first loop starts at that `218`. See the image in question.

Comment: have you tried with the default view at first ?

Comment: Yes, without moving the camera and leaving it at its default position. Also drawing the tiles from x = 0 and y = 0. This works but it should start at the center of the map so you can move in each direction instead of only to the bottom right. Tiles are not saved with a negative value, so I have to create that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. It was a very stupid mistake...

At first without drawing anything, it is normal to center the view on `0.5f * sf::View::getSize()` to get the view centered in your window. So the center was already at half of my window size. When using `Camera::setLocation()`, I used the `sf::View::move()` to move the view accordingly. So when trying to center it on the map, it added the x and y correctly, but also half of my window size. This resulted in having an offset which was incorrect. Substracting or leaving those values out has fixed this stupid problem.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted so people know that the question has an answer that solved the problem.

Comment: Will do, but is not possible in the first 24 hours.